# Variable value changes (according to alert()) but is ignored by plugin code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, onchange

I'm using the following code to change a variable in my plugin. The variable is the delay in a slideshow:

```
$('input[name=changeDelay]').change(function() {
    settings.delay = $(this).val();
});
```

When I alert the modified value, I get my change, but the problem is the delay doesn't actually change in the slideshow. If I change the delay manually, it works fine.

It is being changed. That works. The slideshow appears to not take this new value though, is there a way of making it?

**Here's a demonstration of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/wdqPN/**

Comment: We have no idea how `settings.delay` interacts with the slideshow code. You need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: Here's the example, this is the first one I've ever made so I'm sure you'll spot more than one issue. http://jsfiddle.net/wdqPN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider plugin doesn't know what to do with the value because it's a string. You have to parse it into an int for it.

Change:

```
settings.delay = $(this).val();
```

to

```
settings.delay = parseInt(this.value, 10);
```

Comment: Perfect, for some reason I thought .val would make it an integer, I'm guessing it was coming through as a string?

Comment: @BrockAdams thanks for the edit. to clarify I had parseInt(this.value) but it should be parseInt(this.value, 10). mine would fail for some specific values. if you're parsing ints always set the radix http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score -1):

The better way would be to save your settings in a separate variable at first time in the plugin.

```
var  slideDelay=settings.delay;
$('input[name=changeDelay]').change(function() {
    slideDelay = $(this).val();
});
```

maybe this fiddle could speak to you:

http://jsfiddle.net/wdqPN/2/